# To access S3 bucket from R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have set-up R on an EC2 Instance on AWS.
I have few csv files uploaded into a S3 bucket.
I was wondering if there is a way to access the csv files in the S3 bucket from R.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I use `RAmazonS3`. `install.packages("RAmazonS3", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type = "source")` may work for you to install.

Comment: @jdharrison - while I am trying to install the package on Windows it works fine but when I try to install the same on ubuntu EC2 instance hosted on AWS, I get the following error while trying to install from the R console:-ERROR: dependency ‘bitops’ is not available for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RCurl’
ERROR: dependencies ‘RCurl’, ‘digest’ are not available for package ‘RAmazonS3’
* removing ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RAmazonS3’

Comment: @jdharrison - and when trying to install the same package from R studio installed on the EC2 machine ,the following error:-checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
You must install Digest::HMAC_SHA1
checking for md5sum... /usr/bin/md5sum
Install the relevant software ( Digest::HMAC_SHA1) and then run this configuration again.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RAmazonS3’
* removing ‘/home/r/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RAmazonS3’

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the cloudyr `aws.s3` package (https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3), it might do what you need. Unfortunately (at time of writing), this package is quite early stage & a little unstable.

I've had good success simply using R's `system()` command to make a call to the AWS CLI. This is relatively easy to get started on, very robust and very well supported.

1. Start here: http://aws.amazon.com/cli/
2. List objects using S3 API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html
3. Get objects using S3 API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html

So, for example, on command-line try following:

```
pip install awscli
aws configure
aws s3 help
aws s3api list-objects --bucket some-bucket --query 'Contents[].{Key: Key}'
aws s3api get-object --bucket some-bucket --key some_file.csv new_file_name.csv
```

In R, can just do something like:

```
system("aws s3api list-objects --bucket some-bucket --query 'Contents[].{Key: Key}' > my_bucket.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following command: `install.packages("AWS.tools")`

From there, use the `s3.get()` command.  The `Help` tab should tell you what goes in for arguments.

Comment: AWS.tools has been archived CRAN at the request of the maintainer, who is now working on a replacement package called Rawscli.

Answer (score -2):

Install the `libdigest-hmac-perl` package;

```
sudo apt-get install libdigest-hmac-perl
```