# Access S3 bucket from AWS EC2 via r command lines

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have tried a number of things put files into my EC2 Rstudio instance, particularly uploading via putty, adding dropbox (via Louis Aslett's AMI, but only very small files sync), using filezilla and also winscp.  Unfortunately after several months I can get them in, but they are corrupted on arrival.

There are some older questions related to this

[To access S3 bucket from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268333/to-access-s3-bucket-from-r)

but they all quote packages that are no longer maintained or have no accepted answer.
This seems possible in python using boto and there are alot more answered questions on this via python.

I think maybe AWS might prefer using S3, so I am trying that, is there any r  package that is current and works for uploading into EC2 from S3.  I have set up EC2 and S3?  Does anyone have the r code lines to use and is there anything behind the scenes that needs to be done.  I was told by a colleague it was possible to do this in r with only 4 lines of r code, once the packages were installed, but she does not know how to actually do it.