# Loading remotely stored dataframe into a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I want to use a dataframe as the basis of my shiny app, but I don't want to reload all the raw csv files to run it.

When working in RStudio I use:

```
saveRDS(dfr2, file="dfr.rds")
```

to save the desired `df` and

```
dfr <- readRDS("dfr.rds")
```

to load it.

However, this works only if the files are in my working directory.

How do I get my shiny app to retrieve the `df` from a remote location?

Comment: Why can't you just provide the full path to the file? Something like `readRDS("/User/GaryFH/Documents/dfr.rds")`, assuming you're using OS X, or `readRDS("/home/GaryFH/Documents/dfr.rds")` if you're using Linux.

Comment: I don't think the shiny server on which the app would be running has access to my local drive.

Comment: I suppose that I am not sure what remote locations a shiny app can access and what code should be placed where to access data?    Any examples?

Comment: Not really, because "remote locations" is vague. Consider editing your question to include details of where your app is running (shinyapps.io? a cloud instance that you control?). If your server runs on a cloud instance, and you have SSH access, the answer is most likely using SFTP or SCP to move/copy your .rds file to the instance.

Comment: I'm using shinyapps.io.   Data remotely means from the cloud..  Specifically I am thinking of the data being stored via Amazon S3.

Comment: Looks like there's a package for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268333/to-access-s3-bucket-from-r https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3

Comment: I found I could access my .rds files,  once saved in google drive,  in my shiny app with the following code:    df<-readRDSgzconurl"https://drive.google.com/..."))).    Thanks for your help

Comment: I found I could access my .rds files,  once saved in google drive,  in my shiny app with the following code:    df<-readRDS(gzcon(url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=...")))    Thanks for your help    NOTE drive should be preceded by https:// - for some reason this part of my comment is was not saved.